# Bitpay PHP client installation via composer not working

Tags: php, payment-gateway, bitcoin

I am trying to install bitpay client from: https://github.com/bitpay/php-bitpay-client

I have tried following command line:
[image]

I have following settings:

```
PHP version: 5.4.3
PHP Extensions enabled: php_curl, php_gmp
```

The composer.json has following content:

```
{
    "require": {
        "bitpay/php-client": "~2.0"
    }
}
```

Anyone help me to setup bitpay? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you have those extensions enabled in CLI.

Comment: How do i check this ? extension in CLI ?

Comment: Issue this from the command line: php -i